# WxWidgets Compile Help

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, static-libraries, precompiled-headers, object-files

I tried to compile WxWidgets (Latest; VC9; Release), but it outputted only *.obj and *.pch files, no *.lib files. I know *.obj files are Object Files and *.pch files are Pre-Compiled Headers, but do I reference them from C++ or do I somehow have to convert them into *.lib files.

Btw, I've never used *.pch and am not at all familiar with them. I've only been using C++ for a few months now...

Comment: Look inside the build directory of your project. Or if that doesn't exist (its been a while since I used VC++) search for a directory called debug or release, or if that fails, search for *.lib. Also how are you building wxWidgets? iirc the project has multiple sub projects which you can build. Make sure you are selecting the 'Build All' option in VC++.

Comment: Ah, looking at the build log I'm noticing a few file errors... Gonna have to fix those. Does anyone know of where I can get a precompiled version of WxWidgets?

Comment: yes use wxPack http://wxpack.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

As a static library, a .lib is just a collection of .obj files. You can get that by selecting "Static Library" as the project type in Visual Studio.